# How to control where a Bootstrap btn-group (flex-wrap) breaks to a new row?

Tags: bootstrap-4

Say you have a row of multiple buttons, is it possible to control how the wrapping of 'flex-wrap' is done? In the example below, the first wrapping that occurs will move the last button to a new line, resulting in 7 buttons on top and one huge button in the newly added second row, which isn't very pretty.

Is there a way to split the buttons more evenly, in the example below it should ideally lead to a 4-4 split initially?

```
<div class="btn-group flex-wrap btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b1" name="options" type="radio">Button 1
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b2" name="options" type="radio">Button 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b3" name="options" type="radio">Button 3
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b4" name="options" type="radio">Button 4
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b5" name="options" type="radio">Button 5
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b6" name="options" type="radio">Button 6
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b7" name="options" type="radio">Button 7
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-primary">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="b8" name="options" type="radio">Button 8
    </label>
</div>
```